# get content of td element in spotify template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spotify

I am working with the spotify web API and downloaded their tutorial on getting users playlist. That part works perfectly. But I've added the track id to the table and now I want to store it in a variable when click a specific tablerow. this is spotifys code the id part:

```
  <script id="playlist-detail-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      <p>{{{description}}}</p>
      {{#if images.length}}
      <img style="background-image:url({{images.0.url}})" class="cover"/>
      {{/if}}
      <table id="clickable">
          <tr>
              <th>Track</th>
              <th>Artist</th>
              <th>Album</th>
              <th>Track URI</th>
          </tr>
      {{#each tracks.items}}
          <tr >
              <td>{{track.name}}</td>
              <td>
                  {{#each track.artists}}
                      {{name}}
                  {{/each}}
              </td>
              <td>{{track.album.name}}</td>
              <td class="trackID">{{track.uri}}</td>
          </tr>
      {{/each}}
      </table>
  </script>
```

and this is my code to extract the id:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#clickable tr').click(function() {
        console.log('Function executed');
        var trackID = $(this).find('.trackID').text();
        console.log(trackID);
    });
});
```

The extract code works perfectly because I've tried it on a table that i made myself.But when I click absolutely nothing happens. It doesn't even log the 'Function executed' part. I'm guessing it's because of the fact that it is some scripted template thing that I've never seen before, but I have no idea what to do to fix it. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using click? $('#clickable tr').click(function() {

Comment: because i want something stored when the tablerow is clicked. what should i use instead?

Comment: Try my solution below, let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#clickable tr').each(function() {
        console.log('Function executed');
        var trackID = $(this).find('.trackID').html();
        console.log(trackID);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this didn't work. I still didn't reach the elements inside the scripted template for some reason. Also I think you misunderstood my intentions. I wanted to store the ID of the specific track in a variable when the table row was clicked be the user. With this solution, it loops through all the tracks.

Comment: Couldn't test it due to your template code with "{" but try by just replacing .val with .html in your code

Comment: Yeah but that's the thing. This code works, because I've tried it at a different table written in regular HTML, not generated by a spotify template and it works flawlessly. However when I try it on the spotify template table, absolutley nothing happens. Not even the console.log('Function executed') is executed. So the problem isn't that I don't get the content of the tr, it's that the tr doesn't react when clicked.

Comment: The "Spotify" template is a Handlebars template. Find the element, compile the template with Handlebars and inject it in the page.